# Add lines of code depending on folder structure - Precompiler?

Tags: angular, directory, angular2-directives, precompile

I have objects of different types. Nevertheless, I want to display all types in one Angular2 component of mine.
Here's the code I use for that:

```
in for-loop:
<div [ngSwitch]="Type">
    <c-test *ngSwitchCase="'Test'"></c-test>
    <c-test2 *ngSwitchCase="'Test2'"></c-test2>
    <etc>
</div>
```

Over time, my application could expand, adding new "types" of objects. Since I use the kind of code above in different places, I do not want to add a line in all of these places for each added type. Is there a way of using something similar to the C++ precompiler that will go over my folder-structure and add these lines accordingly?

Example: Let's say I have the following folder-structure.

```
Objects
|- TypeA
|- TypeB
|- etc
```

In my code, I will then have something like this:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="Type">
    <precompile *ngFor="some looping through folders">    
        <"c-$FoundFolder" *ngSwitchCase="'$FoundFolder'"><"c-$FoundFolder">
    </precompile>
</div>
```

Resulting in:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="Type">
    <c-TypeA *ngSwitchCase="'TypeA'"></c-TypeA>
    <c-TypeB *ngSwitchCase="'TypeB'"></c-TypeB>
    <etc *ngSwitchCase="'etc'"></c-etc>
</div>
```

I know that what I want does not exist in this form, but is there a way of achieving something similar, and if yes, how so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below approach doesn't work exactly as per your requirement. But, the basic intend is to load a new component dynamically in future without changing the rendering view, based on new component added to the application. There is a nice article on angular website on this:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html

Just that, it will remain same for the new declaration of component, just you need to make an additional entry in **entryComponent** for each new component added in the same module file where the new component is declared:

`entryComponents: [ HeroJobAdComponent, HeroProfileComponent ],`

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to be very close to what I wanted to do! I'll try it out and comment on how it goes.

Comment: There's a small problem I have with this method. In the documentation, they use a function returning all possible components with their data. However, I'd like to load a component by knowing the name only (Or something similar). Basically, to take the example of the documentation: Instead of `<add-banner [ads]="ads"></add-banner>`, where ads is already loaded, I'd like to do: `<add-banner [ad]="MyAdType"></add-banner>`, where MyAdType is a string or file or whatever that will be used to load the component by add-banner. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you please create a sample plunker and explain me what you want to achive. May be then I will be able to help you. Thanks!